# Visual studio 2012 cannot load assembly

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to build a VB.net project which is already working in another system. I'm facing the below issue.

```
Reference.svcmap: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

kindly help me Im very new to this.

Answer (score 2):

This might help you
http://alanfeekery.com/2012/09/03/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-error-in-visual-studio-2012/

I think the best solution is on Chris Towles blog, just adjust your Service Reference Settings to disable “Reuse types in references assemblies”. Problem solved.

Comment: How exactly would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Hatjhie's solution worked like charm.

Path to reach to the checkbox "Reuse types in references assemblies" is as below:

1. Find the Reference.svcmap file.
2. Right click on Reference.svcmap. Choose Configure Service Reference..
3. You should be able to find "Reuse types in references assemblies" checkbox